# Django hangs on {% url %} template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I have Django installation, which worked fine before. Now it hangs for 5 minutes and then connection timeouts.

After some investigation I have found out, that it hangs while trying to reverse URL in template. So here is the summary:

1. Devserver works fine with the same code on the same machine
2. Django under Apache WSGI works fine (url dispatcher, views handler, template engine) for templates without {% url %} tag
3. reverse('search') in django shell works fine
4. {% url search %} hangs (without using CPU or eating memory - just hangs)

I also checked the cache engine (memcached) and celery+rabbitMQ - everything works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give us details about the urls.py file? Is the view name search, or the view function is called search? Does changing search to the full name "appname.seach" help?

Comment: 'search' is just an example. I have both generic and class-based views and this tag hangs with all of them.
This tag hangs even with non-existing view name ('blah-blah').

Comment: have you tried to run server with --noreload parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's appeared to be a problem with scipy package.
For some reason whenever I install python-scipy package (sudo apt-get install python-scipy) the django stops working. Still have no idea why, but after removing of this package, it came back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps farfetched, but in 1.5 {% url 'path.to.some_view' %} is the way to do it (note the apostrophes.) It couldn't hurt to see if that works.